# Do - While loop does not move on after user inputs correct or incorrect parameters

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to allow the user to input what they want into the program but restricted to the three options of, R, T and Q. I have tried to do this several times and ended up going back on myself several times. I came up with this solution but now when I run the code it simply loops round no matter what I enter into the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

public class Draw {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String[] options = {"R","T","Q"};
String choice;
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(options);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
do {
        System.out.println("Press 'R' to start drawing a Rectangle.");
        System.out.println("Press 'T' to start drawing a Triangle.");
        System.out.println("Press 'Q' to stop.");

        System.out.print("Enter one of the options: "); 
        choice = scanner.next();
        if (options.equals("R")) {
            System.out.println("You have selected to draw a Rectangle!");
            System.out.println("Please enter the Height and Width of the rectangle that is within 30cm - 90cm: ");

        }
        else if (options.equals("T")) {
            System.out.println("You have selected to draw a Tringle! Enter the three angles of the triangle between 30cm and 90cm: ");

        }
            else if (options.equals("Q")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for drawing with the finch, good bye.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again. Enter with a capital letter one of the three options.");
            }
}
while(!list.contains(choice.toLowerCase()));
```

}

Comment: You are checking `options.equals`, not `choice.equals`. Also, what's the guard condition on the loop meant to do? There are no lowercase letters in `options` - why not simply `while (true)`?

Answer (score 3):

Try to write  the `if` condition with using `choice` instead of `options` like this:

```
 if ("R".equals(choice)) {
 ...
 else if ("T".equals(choice)) {
 ...
 else if ("Q".equals(choice)) {
```

And remove the method `toLowerCase` from while loop it's unnecessary:

```
while(!list.contains(choice));
```

Comment: seconding the `while` thought :)

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions are checking the wrong variable:

```
choice = scanner.next(); 
if (options.equals("R")) {
```

should be

```
choice = scanner.next(); 
if (choice.equals("R")) {
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! Such a small and silly mistake. Greatly appreciate all the help.